# Installing Laravel 10 in a Subfolder

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-10

I am attempting to install my Laravel 10 project in a subfolder so that I can access it at `example.com/laravel-project/` instead of `example.com/laravel-project/public/`. Here is the .htaccess configuration I tried in the `/laravel-project/` directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/ [L]
</IfModule>
```

This configuration results in a Laravel-styled 404 error when accessing the subfolder URL. I've reviewed other questions and it seems that something has changed in Laravel 10 that prevents this setup from working as it did in previous versions. I'd like to avoid using `php artisan serve`. Additionally, I have the following set in my .env file, which should also be correct:

```
#...
APP_DIR=laravel-project
APP_URL=http://example.com/laravel-project
#...
```

How can I configure the .htaccess file or Laravel 10 setup to correctly render the homepage at the subfolder URL without having to go to `public/` in the URL?

Edit: The site will be on shared hosting

Comment: Maybe a different approach will be helpful here. How about fundamentally changing folder structure? In the [example](https://github.com/hannanstd/change-laravel-public) you could replace “public_html” with “laravel-project”.

Comment: With the original ``public/.htacess`` file, you can try to add an Alias entry: ``Alias /laravel-project /full_path_to_project/laravel-project/public`` and add ``RewriteBase /laravel-project`` after ``RewriteEngine on`` and save. It should work if your hosting provider allows ``AllowOverride`` !

Comment: The [apache documentation for Alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) shows you in the **context** that you cannot use Alias in .htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue. The `.htaccess` file with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/ [L]` was correct. Here's the additional configuration I made:

I added a new environment variable for the asset URL:

```
ASSET_URL=http://example.com/laravel-project
APP_DIR=laravel-project
```

I updated the RouteServiceProvider (`app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`) to prefix the routes with the subdirectory name:

```php
public function boot(): void
{
    $this->routes(function () {
        Route::middleware('api')
            ->prefix(env('APP_DIR').'/api')
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

        Route::middleware('web')
            ->prefix(env('APP_DIR'))
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    });
}
```

---

Update: Throughout my "adventures" with installing Laravel in a subfolder, I also encountered issues with other tools. I've described more here: https://gist.github.com/rafaucau/8259400871607bfb0826ba7f40b28474

Answer (score 0):

I would do it at the Web Server level using [Virtual Host Aliases](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html) as you seem to be using Apache.

Untested:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/default-site
    Alias /laravel-project /var/www/laravel-app/public

    <Directory /var/www/default-site>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/laravel-app>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

That should enable you to navigate to `example.com/laravel-project` and see your public folder.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, the site will be on shared hosting, so unfortunately, I won't be able to configure Virtual Hosts as you described.